# Getting Google's Streaming Speech to Text Sample Code Running?

Tags: javascript, node.js, speech-to-text, google-speech-api

I'm trying to get streaming speech-to-text running for a node application, and while it runs, it just immediately terminates instead of listening.

I'm following Google's quickstart guides here for basic setup: https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/quickstart-client-libraries
and here for streaming:
https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/streaming-recognize

I've followed every step exactly, but when I run the file (`node speechsample.js`), it says "`Listening, press Ctrl+C to stop.`" like it's supposed to, and then immediately terminates.

My code is exactly as in the google sample, except with `recordProgram: 'sox'`, as that's what the guide says to install.

To my understanding, the application should continue to run, sending an audio stream to the google speech endpoint, and then logging results in the console as they return, but instead the app just ends.

Comment: `recordProgram: sox` does not sound right. Where exactly in the guide you have seen that?

Comment: From the second guide: `recordProgram: 'rec', // Try also "arecord" or "sox"`

Comment: UPDATE: So I found that `rec` is supposed to run sox in record mode, but for some reason that isn't working. I added the sox folder to my environment variables so the path should work, and while I can run `sox`, bash still won't recognize `rec` as valid.

Comment: You can specify an absolute path to the binary in case you have problems